# How to prevent prettyR describe() from printing in console

Tags: r, statistics

I am using the prettyR package's describe function to calculate the mean, standard deviation, median, kurtosis and skewness of a dataset. The code I use is as follows:

```
library(prettyR)

a <- describe(data,num.desc=c("mean","sd","median","kurtosis","skewness"))
```

The dataset in question however is very long so the function proceeds to print the whole list of data in the R console under "description of structure". This takes a long time and makes it hard to read results of previous code in the console due to lots of scrolling required. The output in the console looks as follows:

```
Description of structure(list(x=c(...)),row.names=c(...),class="data.frame")
```

Is there any way to prevent the above output from printing in the console? I just want the a object so I can call it to look at the mean etc. Any help would be much appreciated as the R documentation has been getting me nowhere!

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this and (knowing how this is implemented internally) I suspect your actual code is different from your example.

Comment: However, you could simply use the `xname` argument. See `help("describe")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badly implemented `cat`, should be `message`, not so pretty. Wouldn't use such packages, also not maintained since 4 years.

However can be silenced with `capture.output` into something.

```
nul <- capture.output(des <- prettyR::describe(mtcars))

des
#  Numeric 
#        mean median      var     sd valid.n
# mpg   20.09  19.20    36.32   6.03      32
# cyl    6.19   6.00     3.19   1.79      32
# disp 230.72 196.30 15360.80 123.94      32
# hp   146.69 123.00  4700.87  68.56      32
# drat   3.60   3.70     0.29   0.53      32
# wt     3.22   3.33     0.96   0.98      32
# qsec  17.85  17.71     3.19   1.79      32
# vs     0.44   0.00     0.25   0.50      32
# am     0.41   0.00     0.25   0.50      32
# gear   3.69   4.00     0.54   0.74      32
# carb   2.81   2.00     2.61   1.62      32
```

Better use `psych::describe(mtcars)`.

Comment: (Even weirder to me is that neither of the package authors' github pages ([jimlemon](https://github.com/jimlemon?tab=repositories) and [phgrosjean](https://github.com/phgrosjean?tab=repositories)) list `prettyR` in their lists of repositories.)